# how to add different jquery ui theme to visual studio 2012 MVC4 Project

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Can some explain to me step  by step how i can change  jquery ui themes in visual studio 2012,
For example when i use this  command, Install-Package jQuery.UI.Themes.lightness, how do  i make ui-lightness to appear or if i choose another theme how to display it as well. The reason is because i don't want to use  default theme which is the Base theme. i want to know the right file to change

Any help will be appreciated.

This is what i have already in my layout page.

```
   @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/css")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/css")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First make sure you are bundling the correct files.

**App_Start/BundleConfig.cs**

```
// you want to remove this
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
   "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.core.css",
    ...
);
// and add this
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/css").Include(
    "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.core.css",
    ...
);
```

Then specify the bundled set in your layout.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")          // remove this
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/css")  // add this
```

This all assumes you installed the theme in `/Content/themes`

Easiest thing to do is find `base` and replace it with `ui-lightness` in your layout and bundle config.